# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment using csv file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

Making a currency converter but i have an error, firstly prints

```
sorry not a valid currency
```

after

```
Pound Sterling


Please enter the amount of money to convert: 100
['Pound Sterling', 'Euro', 'US Dollar', 'Japanese Yen']
Please enter the current currency: 'Euro'
1.22
Please enter the currency you would like to convert to: 'Pound Sterling'
Sorry, that is not a valid currency
81.9672131148
```

then a local variable error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in ?
    converter()
  File "//server01/ICT2124/Task 1/Currency Converter 2.py", line 19, in converter
    exchange()
  File "//server01/ICT2124/Task 1/Currency Converter 2.py", line 65, in exchange
    newAmount = int(toPound)*float(newRt)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'newRt' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

heres the code pls help

```
def exchange():
    crntAmnt = int(input("Please enter the amount of money to convert: "))
    print(currencies)
    exRtFile = open ('exchangeRate.csv')
    exchReader = csv.reader(exRtFile)
    crntCurrency = input("Please enter the current currency: ")
    for row in exchReader:
            currency = row[0]
            if currency == crntCurrency:
                crntRt = row[1]
                print(crntRt)
                break
    else:
        print("Sorry, that is not a valid currency")


    newCurrency = input("Please enter the currency you would like to convert to: ")
    for row in exchReader:
            currency = row[0]
            if currency == newCurrency:
                newRt = row[1]
                print(newRt)
                break
    else:
        print("Sorry, that is not a valid currency")


    toPound = crntAmnt/float(crntRt)
    print(toPound)
    newAmount = int(toPound)*float(newRt)
    print("You have: " ,newAmount, newCurrency,)
    return
```

Comment: @Wooble: Doesn't matter here, does it? And the `print()` functions with multiple arguments is not a clue either? :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters: he's entering quotes around the input to `input()`. This will produce the correct strings (in the wrong way, granted...) in Python 2, and e.g. `"'Euro'"` in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

`newRt` is *only* set if you have rows in `exchReader` *and* `if currency == newCurrency` is `True` for a row.

Since the rest of the code cannot reasonably be run without a matching currency, just return at that point:

```
else:
    print("Sorry, that is not a valid currency")
    return
```

The reason that you don't have rows in `exchReader` is that you cannot loop over the CSV reader *twice*; you'd be better off storing all data from the file in a dictionary:

```
with open('exchangeRate.csv') as exRtFile:
    exchReader = csv.reader(exRtFile)
    currencies = {row[0]: float(row[1]) for row in extchReader}

crntCurrency = input("Please enter the current currency: ")
if crntCurrency not in currencies:
    print("Sorry, that is not a valid currency")
    return

newRt = currencies[newCurrency]

toPound = crntAmnt / crntRt
print(toPound)
newAmount = int(toPound) * newRt
print("You have: ", newAmount, newCurrency)
```

Comment: no because then i cant change save changes which will come later

Comment: @user3165683: you have a `return` statement later *anyway*.

Comment: @eryksun: I punted on the whole issue by creating a dictionary instead.

Comment: @eryksun: in this case, the other option is to first ask for both currencies, then scan the CSV *once* to find both.

Comment: @eryksun: if the file is that big, you really don't want to loop twice.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where the expression:

```
if currency == newCurrency
```

evaluates to false the variable newRt which is trying to be accessed in the
unconditional (i.e. is it executed every time) statement:

```
newAmount = int(toPound)*float(newRt)
```

is not initialized and hence an 
error will be raised

(edit) as Martin suggested you should add a return statement under the:

```
print("Sorry, that is not a valid currency")
```

which means that now it should look like this:

```
print("Sorry, that is not a valid currency")
return
```

Comment: I am a beginner and dont understand i though i initialized in the previous 'for ' statement

Comment: Right but let's put it this way: the varaible newRt "gets" a value only in the case where the currency == newCurrency. If the currency == newCurrency is False then the newRt won't have any value and when you try to access it later it will throw an error